# Receive POST in angular 5 page

Tags: angular, angular5

I've got an angular page where I query a webservice and then do a bunch of processing on the data and end up with say 100 names.  On the HTML page I'm just showing the number 100, but if I click on that I want to go to a **new page** where I display all 100 actual names.  Obviously that's too much data to pass in the URL string.

I'm not sure how to post to an angular page directly though.  What's the right way to deal with this?

This is not a parent/child relationship on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to store those 100 names in a client-side Angular service. Then you can access the service from either page to show the 100 or show the 100 names.

A service is a simple class that can be implemented as a singleton, meaning data you assign to the service remains in the service even after you move from one component to another.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string;    // <-- Your data would be stored here
}
```

After retrieving the data, you can store it in the service using simple code like this:

```
export class MainComponent {

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

  getData() {
     // whatever code you are using now to get the data.
     this.dataService.serviceData = retrievedData;
  }
}
```

Then in the new component that you are routing to, you would simply get the data like this:

```
export class OtherComponent {

  get data():string { 
    return this.dataService.serviceData; 
  } 

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { } 
}
```

Then your OtherComponent can bind to the data using the `data` property.

Comment: Although this is a possible solution, it doesn't sound right to create a service just to hold data.

Comment: In all of my Angular courses, presentations, and seminars, I mention sharing data as a *key* purpose of services. But whatever.

Comment: I don't argue that, it can be the right way to do it I guess. But from my background of languages it seemed a bit unusual.

Comment: Using an @Input() property is definitely much easier ... making the big assumption that the OP is working with parent/child components.

Comment: I need to send them to a new page.  The thing they click is housed along with a bunch of other stuff, so just showing it inline won't really work well.  It seems like @Input won't really work for that as I'm understand the documentation.

Comment: Storing this in a service doesn't make sense as I'd have to pull data from the service, process it, send it back up to the service, and then send them to a new page that then re-accesses that updated information.

Comment: Just to be clear ... I'm referring to a client-side Angular service ... not a back end service.

Answer (score 0):

The interaction between components is done through their `Input` and `Output` properties. Refer to [this](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs) link for more information.

So basically you pass your data by using such properties from one component to the other.

Comment: This is *only* true of the components have a parent and child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular is a Framework for SPAs it's not a perfect solution to POST pass your data to the "details view". You could follow the getting [started guidelines](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) and pass the information to a child component using `@Input` properties.